# Setting the version number in an NCBI c++ toolkit app

Tags: c++, toolkit, ncbi

How can I set the version number in a [NCBI C++ Toolkit](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/ToolBox/CPP_DOC/) Application?

I mean the version number which is displayed when I start my program with the parameter -version.

I read through the docs, but have not found it yet.

(I know this is a highly specific question, but I figured it was worth a try)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a void Init(void) method containing code along the following lines:

```
// the last two parameters are optional
CVersionInfo version_info(1, 2, 3, "My App");
SetVersion(version_info);
```

However, this is currently broken (bug already submitted), so the workaround is to give the application class a constructor and call SetVersion from there.